# All given items have the property

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

A card has a type and a color:

```
data CardType = Spades | Clubs | Diamonds | Hearts

data CardColor = Black | Red

cardColor :: CardType -> CardColor

cardColor card =
  case card of Spades -> Black
               Clubs -> Black
               Diamonds -> Red
               Hearts -> Red

type Card = (CardType, CardColor)
```

I want to check whether all the cards have the same color:

```
allTheSameColor :: [Card] -> Bool

allTheSameColor cardList = ???
```

I wonder, how would I do that **without** using any library function such as `filter`? But it's allowed to re-implement it yourself since I want to be able to understand at a deep, functional level how to solve this problem.

Comment: You can see how `filter` and friends are implemented on Hackage; e.g. here is [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-List.html#filter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CardColor` should derive from `Eq` to be comparable:

```
data CardColor = Black | Red
                         deriving (Eq)



allTheSameColor :: [Card] -> Bool
allTheSameColor [] = True
allTheSameColor [x] = True
allTheSameColor (x:y:xs) = if (snd x) == (snd y) then allTheSameColor (y:xs)
                           else False
```

To be more precise, how would you say that the numbers in a list are same? Don't think what steps or procedure you need to figure that, think in terms of relationships between the elements of the list that you need to figure out to find whether the elements of the list are same. That relationship turns out to be this: First element == second element AND second element == third element and so on till the length of the list.

Comment: This is similar to how you would prove inductively that "each item in a series is twice as large as the previous item" etc.

Comment: `That relationship turns out to be this: First element == second element AND second element == third element and so on till the length ` or if the first element is equal to each element.

Answer (score 3):

A function I always have in my module of extra list functions is `allSameBy`.  Like this

```
allSameBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
allSameBy _ [] = True
allSameBy eq (x:xs) = all (eq x) xs
```

Your problem can then easily be solved by

```
allTheSameColor = allSameBy ((==) `on` snd)
```

Alternatively (less efficient), you can define `allSameBy` as

```
allSameBy eq xs = length (groupBy eq xs) <= 1
```

Edit:  Or if you don't want to use any library functions (and slightly different semantics)

```
allSameBy _ [] = True
allSameBy _ [_] = True
allSameBy eq (x:xs@(y:_)) = case eq x y of False -> False; True -> allSameBy eq xs
```

Comment: I like this idea, except that it uses `on` and either `all` or `length` and `groupBy` -- which may be viewed as violating the constraint "without using any library function such as `filter`".

Comment: True, even if I regard reusing existing functions as merit. :)

Comment: I suspect calling `allSameBy` with `(==) \`on\` ...` is quite common. Might be nice to have an `allEqualBy f = allSameBy ((==) \`on\` f`) so that you can write `allEqualBy color` or so (looks pretty!).